# Magento 2: Xml layout update on block embedded in CMS page

Tags: magento2, layout, cms-block

How can I use the Layout Update XML to modify a block that's been embedded in a CMS page. I'm embedding the Magento login block into a CMS page, which works fine, but it does not show the 'Remember Me' checkbox by default. I would like to add the 'Remember Me' checkbox using a Layout Update.

Block embedded in CMS page:

```
{{block 
  class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" 
  template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml" 
  name="customer.login.container"}}
```

Layout Update XML:

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
    <block class="Magento\Persistent\Block\Form\Remember" 
           name="persistent.remember.me" 
           template="Magento_Persistent::remember_me.phtml" 
           before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

The module-persistent customer_account_login.xml uses this same layout update to add the checkbox on the login page so I thought it would work in a CMS page too. I thought wrong.

*Here's a snippet of the login.phtml where the block should render:*
[image: Here's a snippet of the login.phtml where the block should render]

I have tried placing the layout update in the CMS page and also in the cms_page_view.xml file, but the Remember block is never rendered.

Comment: You can achieve it by modifying template file or you want this to be done only using layout file?

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this by following the below steps:**

**Using XML Layout**:

You have to create a layout file specifically for your CMS Page, such as in layout folder of your custom module,

```
cms_page_view_selectable_<CMS Page Identifier>_<Layout Update Name>.xml
```

for example if my CMS page identifier name is testing, I'll name it as **cms_page_view_selectable_testing_loginform.xml** and inside the file I can write code as below to get the login form and remember me option as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Customer Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">            
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info">
                    <block class="Magento\Persistent\Block\Form\Remember" name="persistent.remember.me" template="Magento_Persistent::remember_me.phtml" before="-"/>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And than go to your CMS page in admin and from there under design tab, select your option in Custom Layout Update, whatever you've named it, here I have named it loginform, so I'll select loginform inside my Custom Layout Update.

---

**You can also define blocks as one after another, just saying as a possible way:**

In your CMS page you have to define both blocks such as, in your CMS block:

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml" name="customer.login.container"}}

{{block class="Magento\Persistent\Block\Form\Remember" template="Magento_Persistent::remember_me.phtml" name="persistent.remember.me"}}
```

Now, in your cms_page_view.xml file:

```
<move element="persistent.remember.me" destination="customer.login.container" before="-"/>
```

---

**Another way**:

In your CMS block where you're calling a login block, assign a new template file such as:

```
{{block 
  class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" 
  template="YourCustomVendorName_ModuleName::form/login.phtml" 
  name="customer.login.container"}}
```

Copy ***Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml*** file to ***YourCustomVendorName_ModuleName::form/login.phtml***

And **inside login.phtml file replace**,

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
```

**With**

```
<?php
  echo $this->getLayout()
  ->createBlock('Magento\Persistent\Block\Form\Remember')
  ->setTemplate('Magento_Persistent::remember_me.phtml')
  ->toHtml();
  ?>
```

Now you should have Remember me same as login in your CMS page.